# Why do I have to enter credentials in Report Builder for shared data source?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I am using Report Server 2012 and Report Builder 3.0. I defined a Analysis Services Data Source on the server where I provide windows credentials to access the server.
When I want to add a dataset in Report Builder based on this data source I have to enter credentials. Why? They are defined in the shared data source on the server....
My understanding was, that the data source defined on the report server will use the credentials defined in the data source and not the credentials of the calling client application.